# Angular JS file upload isn't processed properly by connect-multiparty

Tags: express

I have been tearing my hair out for the last couple of hours and I hope someone here could help me out. I have an angular application which is using [(https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and no matter what I try I can't seem to be able to get the files out at the other end.

I do see the correct request payload in the Chrome developer tools:

```
  ------WebKitFormBoundaryEwG0XOfjS0IjwRji
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="images.png"
   Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryEwG0XOfjS0IjwRji-
```

My code on the server side looks as follows, I am using a router which is using connect-multiparty.

Router.js:

```
router.post('/api/v1/uploaddocument', multipartyMiddleware, UserFunctions.saveDocument);
```

The actual save document function:

```
saveDocument: function(req,res)
{   
 console.log(req.body, req.files, req.data, req.file)     
}
```

The controller posting this message in angular is:

```
iSelectClient.controller('PageUploadDocumentCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', function ($scope, Upload) {
    $scope.$watch('files', function () {
        $scope.upload($scope.files);
    });

    $scope.upload = function (files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                Upload.upload({
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/uploaddocument',
                    fields: {'username': $scope.username},
                    file: file
                }).progress(function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data);
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

I am not using app.use(bodyparser()) on the server side, for each individual route I am defining which parser to use.

What o what could it be?

**EDIT**
I had an interceptor on each call which set the application type to json, so it never reached the other end correctly. Fixed now, using the exact same setup as below

Answer (score 0):

I had an interceptor on each call which set the application type to json, so it never reached the other end correctly. Fixed now, using the exact same setup as below